# Need assistance with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I have many strings enclosed within a function called trans. In some places it could be trans('Hello') or trans("Hello")
I want to write a regular expression that returns only Hello in both cases.

```
trans\(\'|"(.*?)\'|"\)
```

This is what I came up with but it doesn't work in my code. Returns other strings as well with single or double quotes. I am using the above in a preg_match_all function as I have to had to escape the single quotes in my regex.

I could also have a string like this within the trans function "It's never happened"

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lGdJbW/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pnbwBk/1

Comment: Please don't answer questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a copy of the opening quotation mark and use it to match the closing quotation mark at the end of the matched string. If back-references worked inside character classes, you could do that with an expression like `/trans\((['"])([^\1]*)\1\)/`, but instead you have to use a negative lookahead — replace `[^\1]*` with `((?!\1).)*`.

Try this:

```php
<?php

$a = <<<END
trans("Double-quoted string")
trans('Single-quoted string')
trans("Apostrophes shouldn't be a problem")
END;

if (preg_match_all('/trans\(([\'"])(((?!\1).)*)\1\)/', $a, $matches) > 0) {
   foreach ($matches[2] as $m) echo "$m\n";
}
else echo "No match\n";
```

Comment: Thank you, the above works. Regex is always like rocket science to me. I missed another instance of the function where I pass arguments as such trans($trans_arr, 'Hello') . Is it possible to have a common solution with the above ? @r3mainer

Comment: You could do that by adding a non-capturing group like `(?:\$\w+, *)?` (if it's non-capturing, it won't affect the back-reference numbering used to match the quotation marks).  Try changing the regular expression to `/trans\((?:\$\w+, *)?([\'"])(((?!\1).)*)\1\)/`